# How does one see the genus of a curve?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, intuition

I know that the genus of a surface is the number of holes. Thus it is easy to "see" just by looking at the surface. I also know that algebraic curves have a genus as well, that appear in the Riemann-Roch theorem. I would like to know if there is also a geometric / visual interpretation of it.

Comment: For instance, the torus appears as an algebraic curve in $\Bbb C^2$ (or rather $P\Bbb C^2$) with its expected genus. But it's not easy to visulaize four (real) dimensions.

Comment: A (smooth, complete) algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ has the structure of a compact Riemann surface (remember that a 1-dimensional complex manifold is a 2-dimensional smooth manifold!)- hence you can visualise genus as in the usual way, at least when over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I expected something like that. However, as said above, it is not easy to see in $\mathbb R^4$. Is there some kind of intuition to imagine what a curve defined over $\mathbb R$ "look like" when see it over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @Régis: I'm going to make a bold statement here an say "no". You pretend it's over $\mathbb{R}$ and think about it that way. Then when you want to prove something you think is true is actually true, you turn to the algebra.